# Working simultaneously on hard drive with Relative URLs and a MOD REWRITE?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's say I'm working on a website in my `c:\website` folder.

If I have relative URLs in my `page.html` like:

`<img src="images/logo.gif">`

It would work fine both when I preview the page on my hard-drive, and if I upload it online.

But since I want to use URL rewriting, let's say my .htaccess has this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/?$ page.html [L]
```

So now the page would get indexed on Google as `domain.com/folder1/folder2/` (which is what I want)

But then, the online file would look for `domain.com/folder1/folder2/images/logo.gif`, which does not exist of course.

On the other hand If I add `/` to my relative URLs like this:

`<img src="/images/logo.gif">`

The online file would look for `domain.com/images/logo.gif` which is good,
But I won't be able to preview the file on my hard drive, as it would look for:

`c:\images\logo.gif` while the file is on `c:\website\images\logo.gif`

Is there any way to be able to make this file properly both on my hard drive and on a website with this sort of URL rewrite rule?

Comment: Generally speaking, your development environment should mirror, as closely as possible, you production environment.  Otherwise, you will always end up with inconsistencies

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to use absolute URLs for your images i.e. `<img src="/images/logo.gif">`

Then you can create a rule like this to handle localhost issue:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(images/.+)$ /website/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

This rule will only fire when an image isn't found (i.e. on localhost) but won't fire on live server as image will be found.

Comment: With what program can I have an htaccess file that would run? right now I'm just working with dreamweaver and preview the files with my browser from the folder, no .htacess is triggered...

Comment: But you already have .htaccess as shown in your question right? What is location of that .htaccess in root OR in `/website/`?

Comment: the .htacess file is only on my online wesbite, and is located in the root of the domain. I don't think it's possible to run an .htacess on my hard drive, which is where I'm previewing my website all the time...

Comment: Well if you don't have Apache running locally then .htaccess won't work

Comment: Yeah, I don't.. so is there any other option? is it possible to make my computer think my root is `c:\website` and not `c:\`?

Comment: I am not sure since the whole question becomes out of bound as there is nothing rewrite module can do then.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how rest of navigation is working for you like loading css/js etc on local hard drive. How can you click on a href link etc. Usually people setup Apache on local server also for development & testing purpose.

Comment: Its the MOD rewrite that forces me to change all `file.type` patterns on all pages to `/file.type` and only then it doesn't work on my HD.